# 2.8 fly mode is crusing like a boat

Tags: navigation

Is there a way to use  cruise controls like the old fly mode without changing too much else in 2.8? (I don't want to revert to 2.7)

I'm using the word cruising as in it moves and will continue to move with or without user input.  Just to specify.  I get that you steer it like a boat.  you set its constant speed with the arrow keys and the focus box will always rotate in the direction of the cursor.  I'm explaining that I know how it works so people don't waste time trying to explain that aspect of it to me.

edit: thought I'd apologies the day after if my question seemed hot headed.  Not walk mode because I don't want to stick to the ground.  I've gotten more used to fly mode if I only use the mouse but you know how it's a box in the screen and it turns for however much your cursor is outside it? how can I make it behave with the cursor fixed and the input from the mouse rotates the view and arrow keys move?  Btw thought I would specify I am speaking about fly mode in edit and object mode.  I'm not talking about anything in the game engine (if there is one in 2.8 didnt check.)

Comment: Did you try the Walk Navigation operator? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You **are** looking for Walk Navigation. It has nothing to do with "sticking to the ground".

Comment: I though walking mode inforced a sense of gravity.  I'm just now transitioning because I got a new computer last week so blender 2.8 is completely fresh.  I watched a few videos about transitioning but none really hit the neich stuff.